# Looping through a hash, or using an array in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, dictionary, hashtable

I'm using this (simplified) chunk of code to extract a set of tables from SQL Server with [BCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_Copy_Program).

```
$OutputDirectory = 'c:\junk\'
$ServerOption =   "-SServerName"
$TargetDatabase = "Content.dbo."

$ExtractTables = @(
    "Page"
    , "ChecklistItemCategory"
    , "ChecklistItem"
)

for ($i=0; $i -le $ExtractTables.Length – 1; $i++)  {
    $InputFullTableName = "$TargetDatabase$($ExtractTables[$i])"
    $OutputFullFileName = "$OutputDirectory$($ExtractTables[$i])"
    bcp $InputFullTableName out $OutputFullFileName -T -c $ServerOption
}
```

It works great, but now some of the tables need to be extracted via views, and some don't. So I need a data structure something like this:

```
"Page"                      "vExtractPage"
, "ChecklistItemCategory"   "ChecklistItemCategory"
, "ChecklistItem"           "vExtractChecklistItem"
```

I was looking at hashes, but I'm not finding anything on how to loop through a hash. What would be the right thing to do here? Perhaps just use an array, but with both values, separated by space?

Or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Christian's answer works well and shows how you can loop through each hash table item using the `GetEnumerator` method. You can also loop through using the `keys` property. Here is an example how:

```
$hash = @{
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
}
$hash.Keys | % { "key = $_ , value = " + $hash.Item($_) }
```

Output:

```
key = c , value = 3
key = a , value = 1
key = b , value = 2
```

Comment: How can I enumerate the hash in another order? E.g. when I want to print its content in ascending order (here a ... b ... c). Is it even possible?

Comment: Why `$hash.Item($_)` instead of `$hash[$_]`?

Comment: @LPrc use the Sort-Object method to do that. This article does a pretty good explanation of it: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx

Comment: You could even use just `$hash.$_`.

Comment: IMO @TNT's comment is the best practise anwer. When $_ is not of type string, only Dot Annotation will not raise ParserError. This should be edited into accepted answer.

Comment: This approach does not work if hashtable contains key = 'Keys'.

Answer (score 259):

Shorthand is not preferred for scripts; it is less readable. The %{} operator is considered shorthand. Here's how it should be done in a script for readability and reusability:

#### Variable Setup

```
PS> $hash = @{
    a = 1
    b = 2
    c = 3
}
PS> $hash

Name                           Value
----                           -----
c                              3
b                              2
a                              1
```

#### Option 1: GetEnumerator()

*Note: personal preference; syntax is easier to read*

The GetEnumerator() method would be done as shown:

```sh
foreach ($h in $hash.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "$($h.Name): $($h.Value)"
}
```

Output:

```
c: 3
b: 2
a: 1
```

#### Option 2: Keys

The Keys method would be done as shown:

```sh
foreach ($h in $hash.Keys) {
    Write-Host "${h}: $($hash.$h)"
}
```

Output:

```
c: 3
b: 2
a: 1
```

#### Additional information

Be careful sorting your hashtable...

[Sort-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176968) may change it to an array:

```
PS> $hash.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object


PS> $hash = $hash.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name
PS> $hash.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

---

[This and other PowerShell looping are available on my blog.](http://blog.vertigion.com/2015/11/18/looping-through-objects/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_campaign=powershell#hashtable)

Comment: like this one more for readability, especially for not dedicate powershell developers like me.

Comment: I agree this method is easier to read and therfore probably better for scripting.

Comment: Readability aside, there is one difference between VertigoRay's solution and Andy's solution.  %{} is an alias for `ForEach-Object`, which is different than the `foreach` statement here.  `ForEach-Object` makes use of the pipeline, which can be much faster if you're already working with a pipeline.  The `foreach` statement does not; it's a simple loop.

Comment: @JamesQMurphy I don't see anything that supports your claim of the pipeline being faster, based on my tests:
https://gist.github.com/VertigoRay/3bb0166d6a877839b420

Comment: @VertigoRay In your test, you are piping $hash.Keys, which is essentially just an IEnumerable, so your results are going to be nearly similar to the pure enumeration case.  The pipeline *can* be much faster, but you will only see that behavior where the pipeline contains results from items running in parallel (like from jobs, or from other servers via Invoke-Command).

Comment: @JamesQMurphy I copy and pasted the answer provided by @andy-arismendi from above; it is the popular pipeline solution for this question. Your statement, which peaked my interest, was that `ForEach-Object` (aka: `%{}`) is faster than `foreach`; **I showed that is not faster**.  I wanted to demonstrate if your point was valid or not; because I, like most people, like my code to run as fast as possible. Now, your argument is changing to running jobs in parallel (potentially using multiple computers/servers) ... which of course is faster than running a job in series from a single thread. Cheers!

Comment: @JamesQMurphy I would also think powershell follows the traditionnal advantage that shells give you when you pipe data streams between several processes: you get natural parallelism from the simple fact that each pipeline stage is an independent process (of course, a buffer may drain and in the end the whole pipeline goes as slow as its slowest process). That's different from having a pipeline process that decides on its own to spawn multiple threads, which is entirely dependent of the implementation details of the process itself.

Comment: __Option 2__ does not work if hashtable contains key = 'Keys'.

Comment: "Foreach" as control flow is not "Powershell-like". It might be more readable for others but not for Powershell developers. Powershell uses pipes whenever it's possible.

Comment: PowerShell was written for easy adoption by novices. Pipes streamline commands in the CLI, but do not improve readability/adoption by novices if used excessively in scripts. It's an argument that will wage on, but one fact remains: real PowerShell developers code in C# and make DLLs for module imports.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do this without a variable

```sh
@{
  'foo' = 222
  'bar' = 333
  'baz' = 444
  'qux' = 555
} | % getEnumerator | % {
  $_.key
  $_.value
}
```

Comment: This gets me a " ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "getEnumerator" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

Answer (score 9):

I prefer this variant on the enumerator method with a pipeline, because you don't have to refer to the hash table in the foreach (tested in PowerShell 5):

```
$hash = @{
    'a' = 3
    'b' = 2
    'c' = 1
}
$hash.getEnumerator() | foreach {
    Write-Host ("Key = " + $_.key + " and Value = " + $_.value);
}
```

Output:

```
Key = c and Value = 1
Key = b and Value = 2
Key = a and Value = 3
```

Now, this has not been deliberately sorted on value, the enumerator simply returns the objects in reverse order.

But since this is a pipeline, I now can sort the objects received from the enumerator on value:

```
$hash.getEnumerator() | sort-object -Property value -Desc | foreach {
  Write-Host ("Key = " + $_.key + " and Value = " + $_.value);
}
```

Output:

```
Key = a and Value = 3
Key = b and Value = 2
Key = c and Value = 1
```

Comment: The enumerator can return the values in **"any"** order, as it simply iterates the underlying implementation. In this case it happens to *appear* be reverse order. For a counter-example: `$x = @{a = 1; z = 2}; $x.q = 3` is "ordered" as q,a,z here.

Comment: ["Ordered dictionaries differ from hash tables in that the keys always appear in the order in which you list them. The order of keys in a hash table is not determined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-6) - the `[ordered]` attribute triggers selection of the different implementation.

Answer (score 7):

About looping through a hash:

```
$Q = @{"ONE"="1";"TWO"="2";"THREE"="3"}
$Q.GETENUMERATOR() | % { $_.VALUE }
1
3
2

$Q.GETENUMERATOR() | % { $_.key }
ONE
THREE
TWO
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is another quick way, just using the key as an index into the hash table to get the value:

```
$hash = @{
    'a' = 1;
    'b' = 2;
    'c' = 3
};

foreach($key in $hash.keys) {
    Write-Host ("Key = " + $key + " and Value = " + $hash[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A short traverse could be given too using the sub-expression operator $( ), which returns the result of one or more statements.

```
$hash = @{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3}

forEach($y in $hash.Keys){
    Write-Host "$y -> $($hash[$y])"
}
```

Result:

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerShell v3, you can use JSON instead of a hashtable, and convert it to an object with [Convert-FromJson](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx):

```
@'
[
    {
        FileName = "Page";
        ObjectName = "vExtractPage";
    },
    {
        ObjectName = "ChecklistItemCategory";
    },
    {
        ObjectName = "ChecklistItem";
    },
]
'@ | 
    Convert-FromJson |
    ForEach-Object {
        $InputFullTableName = '{0}{1}' -f $TargetDatabase,$_.ObjectName

        # In strict mode, you can't reference a property that doesn't exist, 
        #so check if it has an explicit filename firest.
        $outputFileName = $_.ObjectName
        if( $_ | Get-Member FileName )
        {
            $outputFileName = $_.FileName
        }
        $OutputFullFileName = Join-Path $OutputDirectory $outputFileName

        bcp $InputFullTableName out $OutputFullFileName -T -c $ServerOption
    }
```

Comment: n.b. the command is ConvertFrom-Json (and the converse, ConvertTo-Json) -- just swap the dash placement.