# Convert JS format csv to a delimited CSV using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have a sample csv file and tried to convert to a delimited format csv using powershell. For the timestamp part, it was stored as seconds by default, wondering if it can be converted into "hh:mm"

Not too sure where i should start with.

Thanks for help!

sample.csv

```
{
   "Body" : {
      "inverter/1" : {
         "Data" : {
            "Current_DC_String_1" : {
               "Unit" : "A",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=66050"
            },
            "Current_DC_String_2" : {
               "Unit" : "A",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=131586"
            },
            "EnergyReal_WAC_Sum_Produced" : {
               "Unit" : "Wh",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=67830024"
            },
            "Voltage_DC_String_1" : {
               "Unit" : "V",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 7.3000000000000007,
                  "300" : 7.3000000000000007,
                  "600" : 7.9000000000000004,
                  "900" : 7.7000000000000002
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=66049"
            },
            "Voltage_DC_String_2" : {
               "Unit" : "V",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 4.2000000000000002,
                  "300" : 4.2000000000000002,
                  "600" : 4.5,
                  "900" : 4.4000000000000004
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=131585"
            }
         },
         "DeviceType" : 233,
         "End" : "2020-03-11T23:59:59+11:00",
         "NodeType" : 97,
         "Start" : "2020-03-11T00:00:00+11:00"
      },
      "inverter/2" : {
         "Data" : {
            "Current_DC_String_1" : {
               "Unit" : "A",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=66050"
            },
            "Current_DC_String_2" : {
               "Unit" : "A",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=131586"
            },
            "EnergyReal_WAC_Sum_Produced" : {
               "Unit" : "Wh",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 0,
                  "300" : 0,
                  "600" : 0,
                  "900" : 0
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=67830024"
            },
            "Voltage_DC_String_1" : {
               "Unit" : "V",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 6.7000000000000002,
                  "300" : 7,
                  "600" : 6.8000000000000007,
                  "900" : 7.2000000000000002
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=66049"
            },
            "Voltage_DC_String_2" : {
               "Unit" : "V",
               "Values" : {
                  "0" : 2.2000000000000002,
                  "300" : 2.3000000000000003,
                  "600" : 2.2000000000000002,
                  "900" : 2.2000000000000002
               },
               "_comment" : "channelId=131585"
            }
         },
         "DeviceType" : 233,
         "End" : "2020-03-11T23:59:59+11:00",
         "NodeType" : 98,
         "Start" : "2020-03-11T00:00:00+11:00"
      }
   },
   "Head" : {
      "RequestArguments" : {
         "Query" : "Inverter+SensorCard+Meter",
         "Scope" : "System"
      },
      "Status" : {
         "Code" : 0,
         "Reason" : "",
         "UserMessage" : ""
      },
      "Timestamp" : "2020-03-11T01:00:03+11:00"
   }
}
```

**Expected result with default timestamp converted**

[image]

Or if possible can add the date"2020-03-11" parsed from "Start" : "2020-03-11T00:00:00+11:00" in front of converted time to make DateTimestamp for each row.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file is a JSON file, not a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

In order to flatten its object graph into the CSV row-column structure you need, nested loops are required:

```
# Parse the JSON file into custom objects.
$fromJson = Get-Content -Raw file.json | ConvertFrom-Json

& {
  foreach ($inverter in $fromJson.Body.psobject.Properties.Name) {
    $date =  $fromJson.Body.$inverter.Start
    if ($date -is [datetime]) { $date = $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd') }
    else                      { $date = ($date -csplit 'T')[0] }
    foreach ($measurement in $fromJson.Body.$inverter.Data.psobject.Properties.Name) {
      foreach ($valueProp in $fromJson.Body.$inverter.Data.$measurement.Values.psobject.Properties) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
          Inverter  = "$inverter $measurement"
          TimeStamp = $date + ' ' + 
                      [timespan]::FromSeconds([int] $valueProp.Name).ToString('hh\:mm')
          Value     = $valueProp.Value
        }
      }
    }
  } 
} | ConvertTo-Csv  # output CSV data as an array of *strings*; 
                   # to save to a *file*, use something like:
                   # Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv
```

Note how `.psobject.Properties` is used to reflect on a given object's properties; `.psobject` is a normally hidden property available on any object, and it provides reflection information more conveniently and faster than the `Get-Member` cmdlet does.

Also note how the timestamps in your JSON are parsed by `ConvertFrom-Json` depends on the PowerShell edition (version):

- *Windows PowerShell* parses them as *strings*, so it's sufficient to split the string by `T` and take what comes before it.
- *PowerShell [Core]* parses them as `[datetime]` instances, expressed in *local* time, so they're only guaranteed to result in the same calendar day if the local time zone is the same as the one implied by the UTC offset in the JSON values (`+11:00`).

---

**Optional reading: performance considerations**:

Note the use of nested `foreach` *loops* over the use of the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet* in the *pipeline* for better performance.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48888108/45375) for background information.

With small input files that may not matter, however, and [RoadRunner's helpful *hashtable*-based alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60629002/45375), which uses nested pipeline, may well be fast enough in practice - and it too could be made to use `foreach` *loops* instead (*update*: it now does, in a second command).

Parsing the JSON into hashtables (`[hashtable]`, aka [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable)) via
`-AsHashtable`:

- has the *advantage* of requiring less memory (the internal storage of the `[pscustomobject]` instances that `ConvertFrom-Json` outputs by default is somewhat inefficient).
- has the *potential disadvantage* of not preserving the input order of properties, given that `[hashtable]` entries are inherently unordered; in the case at hand, this is not a concern, however, given that different output objects with a fixed property order are created.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is actually a JSON file, and not a CSV file, you could try the approach below. If basicaly converts the JSON file to [`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable?view=netframework-4.8) object with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) using the `-AsHashTable` switch. You can read how to iterate through hashtable properties from [Looping through a hash, or using an array in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015138/looping-through-a-hash-or-using-an-array-in-powershell).

You can then get the [`System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0) rows and pipe to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7), which creates the CSV file. Additionally, you can get the timespan using [`[System.Timespan]::FromSeconds()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netframework-4.8), which converts total seconds to a object of type `System.Timespan` and format `hh:mm` with [`System.TimeSpan.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=netframework-4.8). For more information on timespan formatting, you can have a look at [Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss,fff format in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21842175/convert-seconds-to-hhmmss-fff-format-in-powershell).

As a extra cleanup step, I also went and removed the `"` quotes with [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content?view=powershell-7) as well. This isn't necessary if you would like the `"` to persist in your file.

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\sample.json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$json.Body.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $inverter = $_.Key

    $_.Value.Data.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        $value = $_.Key

        $_.Value.Values.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Inverter = "$inverter $value"
                Second = [timespan]::FromSeconds($_.Key).ToString("hh\:mm")
                Value = $_.Value
            }
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\sample.csv
# Use NoTypeINformation to remove #TYPE from headers in < Powershell 6

Set-Content -Path .\sample.csv -Value ((Get-Content -Path .\sample.csv) -replace '"')
```

**sample.csv**

```
Inverter,Second,Value
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_2,00:05,0
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_2,00:10,0
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_2,00:15,0
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_2,00:00,0
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_1,00:05,0
inverter/1 Current_DC_String_1,00:10,0
...
```

**Performance Improvement**

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60627593/convert-js-format-csv-to-a-delimited-csv-using-powershell/60629106#60629106) explained, when using .NET types or `[PSCustomObject]`, member enumeration is much faster than using pipelines. You can find out more from this helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176815/select-the-values-of-one-property-on-all-objects-of-an-array-in-powershell/48888108#48888108).

Below is simple usage of the improvement that can be made with `foreach` enumeration instead of [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7).

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\sample.json | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

$csvRows = @()

foreach ($inverter in $json.Body.GetEnumerator()) {

    foreach ($outerValue in $inverter.Value.Data.GetEnumerator()) {

        foreach ($innerValue in $outerValue.Value.Values.GetEnumerator()){
            $csvRowData = [PSCustomObject]@{
                Inverter = "$($inverter.Key) $($outerValue.Key)"
                Second = [timespan]::FromSeconds($innerValue.Key).ToString("hh\:mm")
                Value = $innerValue.Value
            }

            $csvRows += $csvRowData;
        }
    }
}

$csvRows | Export-Csv -Path .\sample.csv

Set-Content -Path .\sample.csv -Value ((Get-Content -Path .\sample.csv) -replace '"')
```