# Translating PHP to Powershell

Tags: php, powershell, foreach, hashtable

I'm currently translating a PHP script to Powershell, and I'm stuck at the following part:

```
$data = array();
foreach($extension_data as $key=>$value){
   array_push($data,array("name"=>$key,"value"=>$value));
}
```

Especially, what would the `$key=>$value` part look like in PowerShell?

EDIT: here's my solution

```
    $data = @()
        foreach($e in $extension_data.getenumerator()){
            $data += @{"name" = $($e.name); "value"=$($e.value)}
        }
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015138/looping-through-a-hash-or-using-an-array-in-powershell

Comment: Thx - that did the trick!